# How to detect whether an HTML page contains a video?

Tags: html, video

I would like to know whether it a possible to detect whether a HTML page contains a video.

I know that one possible way is to look for ".swf" in the HTML source code. But most of the pages do not contain the file name.

For example, given following URL and possibly its source code, is it possible to find out whether it contains a video:
http://www.cnn.com/video/

Comment: In general, this is not possible.

Comment: Answer depends on the programming language you'd like to use to detect it.

Comment: Pekka already sums it quite good up. I checked the CNN's site source, it actually uses JS to load the video. Not many HTML parsers will execute/parse JS as well. There are some which will do, but you'll after all need to write target-specific code. There's no generic way. Apart from that, JSP is a view technology. You normally don't want to write Java code in a JSP file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many ways to embed Video into a HTML page - as Flash Video or instances of Platform-Specific players through `<object>` and `<embed>` tags (but not every one of those tags is a video! The same holds true for `.swf` - it's just the file extension of Flash files, Video or not), the new HTML 5 `<video>` tag... They are not impossible to find out but it's a lot of work to catch all possible player types, formats and embed codes, and will result in a lot of false positives / negatives.

Then, there are JavaScript libraries that initialize players after the containing page has loaded - those are almost impossible to detect.

It's still a very complex issue to get video *into* a web page reliably, and subsequently, it's even more complex to find it *out*. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, I would consider dropping it.

Answer (score 2):

For your case (CNN site) you can parse Open Graph micro-markup for a video information.

Meta tags such as `og:video:type, og:image` will help you.

Video hosting services usually support micro-markup, e.g. open graph or scheme.org.

So you can parse these markups.

Answer (score 0):

Check if an `<object>` tag exists in the DOM and check its content type and parameters. You will find the pattern by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You can also search for .flv, or .mp4 in the source code.

Comment: It's extremely unreliable. A Flash movie could contain the reference to the flv file in the movie itself.

Comment: The web pages is playing mp4 or flv or .. videos via iframe don't contain the src of the video in their source!!